# Join Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Active Directory using realm, sssd and adcli

Tags: active-directory, ubuntu-14.04, sssd

I'm setting up a new network with a Windows 2012 machine running AD DS.
I have several Ubuntu 14.04 I want to join in the domain for authentication.
I've managed to do so on one of these servers using realmd, sssd and adcli this was pretty straightforward.

However on at least 2 other servers I cannot get the same setup to work.
The big difference between the two is that they reside in a different subnet.
I've checked:
- Routing
- DNS
- disabled all firewall rules on both the firewall and the DC.

I kan successfully issue a kinit but while joing adcli claims it cannot contact a KDC.

Hopefully you guys can point out my failure.

Kind regards

root@lb02:~# ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: net: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:ea:a5:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet ***.***.***.**/** brd ***.***.***.*** scope global net
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ....
3: www: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:70:11:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.2.1.2/24 brd 10.2.1.255 scope global www
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ....
```

root@lb02:~# cat /etc/krb5.conf

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5.log

[libdefaults]
default_realm = ACME.COM
kdc_timesync = 1
ccache_type = 4
forwardable = true
proxiable = trye

[realms]
ACME.COM = {
        kdc = ad01.acme.com
        admin_server = ad01.acme.com
        default_domain = ACME.COM
}

[domain_realm]
.acme.com = ACME.COM
acme.com = ACME.COM
```

root@lb02:~# klist

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: kvanhagen@ACME.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/08/2015 16:19:55  07/09/2015 02:19:55  krbtgt/PRO4ALL.COM@ACME.COM
        renew until 07/09/2015 16:19:52
```

root@lb02:~# dig -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.acme.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.acme.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13722
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_kerberos._tcp.acme.com.    IN      SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_kerberos._tcp.acme.com. 600 IN      SRV     0 100 88 ad01.acme.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ad01.acme.com.       3600    IN      A       10.2.4.1

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 10.2.4.1#53(10.2.4.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 08 16:24:43 CEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

root@lb02:~# dig -t SRV _kerberos._udp.acme.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> -t SRV _kerberos._udp.acme.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3917
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_kerberos._udp.acme.com.    IN      SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_kerberos._udp.acme.com. 600 IN      SRV     0 100 88 ad01.acme.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ad01.acme.com.       3600    IN      A       10.2.4.1

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.2.4.1#53(10.2.4.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 08 16:46:25 CEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

root@lb02:~# ping -c4 ad01.acme.com

```
PING ad01.acme.com (10.2.4.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ad01.acme.com (10.2.4.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.651 ms
64 bytes from ad01.acme.com (10.2.4.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=0.620 ms
64 bytes from ad01.acme.com (10.2.4.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=127 time=0.721 ms
64 bytes from ad01.acme.com (10.2.4.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=127 time=0.750 ms

--- ad01.acme.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.620/0.685/0.750/0.058 ms
```

C:\Users\Administrator>ping lb02

```
Pinging lb02.acme.com [10.2.1.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.2.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.2.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.2.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.2.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 10.2.1.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

kvanhagen@lb02:~$ telnet ad01.acme.com 88

```
Trying 10.2.4.1...
Connected to ad01.acme.com.
```

root@lb02:~# realm --membership-software=adcli  discover acme.com

```
acme.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: ACME.COM
  domain-name: acme.com
  configured: no
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
```

root@lb02:~# realm --verbose join acme.com

```
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.acme.com
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.2.4.1
 * Successfully discovered: acme.com
 * Unconditionally checking packages
 * Resolving required packages
 * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain acme.com --domain-realm ACME.COM --domain-controller 10.2.4.1 --login-type user --login-ccache=/var/cache/realmd/realm-ad-kerberos-MCBF1X
 * Using domain name: acme.com
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: LB02
 * Using domain realm: acme.com
 * Sending netlogon pings to domain controller: cldap://10.2.4.1
 * Received NetLogon info from: ad01.acme.com
 * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-v7Y0Pg/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-eJg20h
 * Looked up short domain name: ACME
 * Using fully qualified name: lb02
 * Using domain name: acme.com
 * Using computer account name: LB02
 * Using domain realm: acme.com
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: LB02
 * Generated 120 character computer password
 * Using keytab: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
 * Using fully qualified name: lb02
 * Using domain name: acme.com
 * Using computer account name: LB02
 * Using domain realm: acme.com
 * Looked up short domain name: ACME
 * Found computer account for LB02$ at: CN=LB02,CN=Computers,DC=acme,DC=com
 ! Couldn't set password for computer account: LB02$: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm
adcli: joining domain acme.com failed: Couldn't set password for computer account: LB02$: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm
 ! Failed to join the domain
realm: Couldn't join realm: Failed to join the domain
```

Comment: Have you got a firewall somewhere between these two networks?

Comment: can you join using the `net ads join` syntax as described in the [Ubuntu AD Winbind Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto)?

Comment: @Michael Hampton: Yes I do, but I made sure all traffic between these hosts is allowed. Any traffic that is dropped or rejected is logged (unfortunately no results there).

Comment: @the-wabbit: I have not, I am trying to register without using samba. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @the-wabbit: net ads join fails with "DNS update failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL", I can see logon entries in the Security EventLog on ad01. Do you know if MS DNS only allows dynamic updates from the same subnet by default?

Comment: Try setting dns_lookup_kdc in your krb5.conf - I wouldn't worry about the DNS updates from net ads. You should not need Samba to get a kerberos ticket assuming you kinit using your full UPN (kinit user@ADDOMAIN.TLD), I auth against AD with just libnss-ldapd & libpam-krb just fine

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins: With my current (posted) krb5.conf I can succesfully authenticate with kerberos and get a ticket. I think I've found at least part of the issue. adcli creates a temporary krb5.configuration, this configuration does not include the domain but instead maps the dc's fqdn to the realm. Using libnss-ldap & libpam-krb is a good option, is it possible to bind to ldap without storing a password?

Comment: I have not tried, we allow anonymous binds. Looking at the adcli docs, can you post your sssd.conf? Btw, the "DNS Update failed message" can be ignored for most purposes - at least in my experience it comes after succesfully creating the account in AD -but Samba & adcli/sssd do not have to be mutually dependant and your config says it's using SSSD

Comment: Try listening with tcpdump to the DNS traffic to see what realmd is trying to resolve. Alternatively, set KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr to see tracing info from libkrb5.

Comment: I believe this is a [documented bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55487). To my understanding, the error is triggered when, in a multi-DC configuration different operations use different DCs.